# gcloud loadbalancing handshake failure

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a VM that I need to run an additional web server on.

To do this I need to run the second webserver on an alternate port: 1080.

I'm trying to configure a loadbalancer to send traffic to this VM and port.

I've allocated a google managed cert on the load balancer and have the front end taking requests on port 443.

The single VM is in an unmanaged group.

When I attempt to connect:

```
curl --verbose https://ivanhoehandyman.com.au
*   Trying 34.160.171.42:443...
* Connected to ivanhoehandyman.com.au (34.160.171.42) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

The configuration is as follows:

Load balancer:

[image]

The front end:
[image]

The backend:
[image]

Routing rules:
[image]

Comment: There is something wrong with the Frontend. The load balancer is not replying with `Server hello` 1) Verify that the managed certificate has been issued. 2) I would delete the frontend and recreate it. Tip: check the version of curl that you are using and update it if possible. Note: I see the same problem from my network, so this is a Google load balancer issue.